# JS fails unless the console is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm truly stumped by this problem.
I've got some JavaScript to control a product configurator.
A simple bit of code to select some defaults

- works fine in Chrome
- works fine in IE
- doesn't work in Firefox (newest versions of everything)

However, if I do anything to observe the code in FF it **works fine**.

- If I have it alert anything relevant, it works.
- If I log anything relevant, it works, but only if the console is actually open so I can see the log. If the console isn't open, doesn't work.

  ```
   for(type in radio_groups) {
       if_checked = !!$(":radio[name="+type+"]:checked").length;

       console.log($('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]')); 
       //This loop doesnt do anything without this log above

       alert($('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]')); 
       // Or this alert.

       var t = $('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]'); 
       // Line above doesn't make stuff work.

       if(!if_checked)
           $('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]').first().click();
   }
  ```

`if_checked` is false for every `type`, I can verify that when it runs.

However, nothing happens.
No buttons are clicked.
This is plain single threaded JS in a browser.
There's no interval/timeout functions on the page.

I can do time arbitrary time consuming tasks before the last line (my best idea was that it was a concurrency issue somehow, I don't see how else logging could affect anything) and it doesn't have any effect.

I can run the same selector and put it in a string, or do anything you can think of to it besides logging or alerting and it wont work; no buttons get clicked. Only actively observing whats happening makes the code work. The entire deal is rather involved and I cant provide the entire thing.

Any ideas on how:

- logging can possibly affect the outcome of a simple click event?
- why this is Firefox specific? Or other ways I might try to see whats going wrong without the console or alerts?

Edit: Oh, and I've had two other people replicate the issue in their browsers (again, Firefox only), so its not some wonky extension issue unless we all share it.

Thanks.

Comment: is your site live or can u make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Is "if_checked" a global variable? What is "radio_groups"?

Comment: You may want check if console is defined. I would guess Console isnt available unless you have it open maybe?

Comment: why `!!` in  `if_checked = !!` ??

Comment: please paste output of those logs. 
to the line starting with `var t =` - why do you expect it to work?

Comment: try replace console.log with alert

Comment: or try https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill

Comment: create demo that replicates it or speculation will run rampant. As for other logging methods.... `$('body').append('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(obj,null, ' '))`

Comment: What happens when you do this instead? `if(!if_checked)(function(type){setTimeout(function(){$('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]').first().click();}, 0);}(type)());` I'm wondering if that last line needs to run in a different execution context.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not valid:

`var t = "$('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]')";`

It should probably be:

`var t = "$('.'+type).not('[class*=\"unavailable\"]')";`

or:

`var t = $('.'+type).not('[class*="unavailable"]');`

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant the last one, and thats what the code has. But that was just some random junk I was trying because logging that selector makes things work, wanted to show that running the same code without logging it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of speculation:

```
if_checked = !!$(":radio[name="+type+"]:checked").length;
```

It looks like the quotes aren't paired correctly.  Did you mean this?

```
if_checked = !!$(":radio[name='"+type+"']:checked").length;
```

(See the single quotes that wrap the value of `type`?)

Comment: Oh yeah, fixed that. It was working anyways (if_checked was logged and evaluating to what was expected, 'false'), but yar, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this before. If I'm leaving any logging in place in production code I'd wrap it in a try > catch statement.

```
try {
    console.log("my log message")
 } catch (err) { };
```

I know it's considered bad practice to have an empty 'catch' but hey, it's also bad practice to leave the logging in on priduction code.

It seems in FF (also in older IE) if the console is not open then it doesn't exist so the error being caught is probably something like 'console is undefined'

Comment: May as well just shim it instead https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#everything